# How do I add sign in with Apple to firebase pre-built ui?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase has a nice pre-built UI for signin.  I was able to easily add google and email signin to my web app via [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui).

I also noticed that Sign in with Apple is also supported, so I went ahead started following this [flow](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple?authuser=0) to set that up as well.

Unfortunately after setting up everything on the Apple side, I noticed that there is no direct support for Apple in the pre-built UI.  For example while there is a `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID` there is no `firebase.auth.AppleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID`. Can I add this into the pre-built ui,  or do I have to go fully custom just to support sign in with Apple?

---

**Update**

Based on @FrankvanPuffelen answer below. I was able to just use the following to specify my list of sign in providers.

```
signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,  
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
       'apple.com'
    ],
```

Of course it took me an hour to figure out that I had a type in my service identifier name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at the documentation of FirebaseUI for Web, I see that "Sign in with Apple" is mentioned in section on [configuring providers](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configuring-sign-in-providers) and in the list of [available providers](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#available-providers).

From that last link it seems like you should use a string value of `"apple.com"` for "Sign in with Apple", instead of a constant like for most of the other providers. For example, like in this snippet from [ceneric OAuth providers](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#generic-oauth-provider):

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
  signInOptions: [
    'apple.com',
    'microsoft.com',
    'yahoo.com',
  ]
});
```

Finally: if you [search for apple.com in the firebaseui-web repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/search?q=apple.com), you'll find many more relevant code snippets.